# How to make a fail safe system image for Ubuntu Linux VM

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and VMs.

I am working on a 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 Linux VM. I am managing it using VirtualBox 5.0.18. Before I download packages and potentially make changes that could screw up my current VM environment, is there a way to make an image of the VM or something along that line that I can always revert to? So I do not have to destroy my VM and restart from the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: VirtualBox 5.1 has a "Clone" option; I don't have a 5.0 around but it probably has it as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Copy the actual VM image**.

You can do this a couple of ways.  You can use Virtualbox's Snapshot/clone GUI or you can manually copy the image file.

To copy the image file manually locate it from Virtualbox GUI Manager.

1. Right click the Menu Item
2. Click on `Show in File Manager`
3. Copy your Virtual drive (by default the *.vdi file by the name of the virtualbox item.

When you need to have access to the original install, add this *.vdi image to the storage controller in your Settings for that VM.

After adding the drive, you'll have an option of which drive to boot to, or the option of deleting one and only using the other.

**Note:**
The terminal option has the benefit of being able to be automated and copyied to a different location.

The clone option adds an item to the Virtualbox manager.  It also adds a new directory entry to the default `~/VirtualBox VMs` folder.  Since I have a number of copies of my important images, it would be cumbersome to have so many different menu items and separate directories for each image.  The most significant item is the image itself which I manually backup.

Comment: Does this include the files/packages I have already downloaded to my VM?

Comment: Yes.  Everything that is available when you boot into your VM is stored in the image.  The image is the actual virtual drive.  You could take that image, and that image alone and put it into a different computer.  The install Virtualbox.  Set it as your boot drive... boot to it, then have the full access.  The other files are settings files that you use for setting up the actual computer, such as the amount of member, display configurations and other things that don't relate to the physical data on in the actual VM.

Comment: -1 That's just a hacky substitute for VBox's "clone" feature.

Comment: What's the difference between this and creating a snapshot?

Comment: I often make default VM, then burn the image to a USB and use that for performing new installs on new computers.  The system I'm using now (my main system) was created in that manner.  I burned the VM to the SSD that is my **/dev/sda**.

Comment: I have a data drive where I keep various *.vdi's from my many VM's.  They are sorted for various purposes with descriptions.  I find it convenient using the terminal for copying, moving, and organizing my data.  There's not much difference except for the convenience of the GUI for people who don't use the termina.

Comment: @fkraiem For your information, while I believe you seriously miss the point, I didn't downvote your comment.  I don't think using the terminal for backing up and sorting various data on the computer falls so heavily in hacking.  I do this with backups of just about everything I use, even though many applications (such as word processors, programming IDE, database and other servers) have their own GUI way.

Comment: fkraiem'c comment is brusque, but makes a wise point - best practice is to use vbox clone to create copies instead of the OS file manager. Both can create a copy - it's simply a good habit to use and recommend the vbox function...a good habit that stays with you on the days you are using a different OS or restoring from a clone. Thanks for listing it first in the answer.

Comment: @user535733 For your information, it wasn't the OS file browser that was the gist of my second method.  I used the the VM GUI reference and file browser to show where the image was.  Once a user has this option, he can expound on methods of sorting and backing up his images in ways that are not included in the application itself.  I understand that a lot of people feel very compelled to only use a GUI provision from some applications.  The very mention in my answer concerning the specific issue prompted the user to ask and I'm sure now better understand what is included in that image.

Comment: ...with this knowledge a user might find it very convenient to work from command prompts having their images on a server machine that doesn't have a monitor.  This in itself and understanding it can make it easier to manipulate images that are on various clouds.  I didn't mean to take away from what was provided in the comment.  I offer an expansion of what I considered valuable information.  It make working with the environment much easier for me... handling images for my backups rather than full directories.